# Computer Vision for overhead People counting

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

My aim is to count people entering and leaving a bus using overhead camera as shown [in the bus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvcYctV2Ho0) and [in the mall](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDK6nLdm3sQ). How can I do it in Raspberry Pi?

Is there any software or sources or platforms available for it?

Comment: Way too broad to be a good question for this site.  An answer would require a book.  And, if you should be minded to ask, I don't know where you could put this in the hope of getting an answer.

Comment: My first thought after watching the mall video is: That the software can easily assume a constant background (while being calibrated), then on each successive frame it can take diff of the current frame and calibrated frame. This would reduce the search area, Then you may use simple haar cascade to get head area from the contours in the diff frame.

Comment: Search for background subtraction

Comment: I used background subtraction. But the problem here is movement of door,change in light intensity,illumination and shadow of the person will come into play and these thing will be counted up. Is there any better options available?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be the embedded learning library ELL, available on GitHub.

https://microsoft.github.io/ELL/

I have used it for object classification on a pi with good results. There is a tutorial on using region proposals, which is what you would need to count the multiple object instances. The performance on a pi may or may not be sufficient to catch someone that moves through the door passage quickly, but might serve your purposes.